# files disappear from VS 2015 solution after saving

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

After installing VS 2015 Pro (14.0.25... with Update 3, licence key has been succesfully added), and creating a new project (especially in Javascript or TypeScript with Ionic 2 templates), when I open a file, (modified it or not), I save it and it disappear from Solution Explorer. Just before it disappear, the icon of the file is updated with a warning icon.

However, if I try to create a C++ project, there is no problem !

In a typescript project, after building, ts files appear again at the end of the build.

All my projects are located in c: disk. I've tried with and without using git.

The two extensions I've installed are : Ionic 2 templates and NPM Task runner. I uninstalled them, but the problem is still here.

When I restart VS, I can see again the files. But the problem is still here.

How to fix it ?

Comment: I have the same problem, I unload and reload project. But, it is quite annoying. Is there any solution around this?

Comment: Just let you know it works just fine in visual studio code.

Comment: Yep, my solution was also to use visual studio code.

Comment: I am using Windows UWP project but visual studio code does not support it. Is there any way I can continue to use vs 2015 pro on latest windows upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue on Windows 10.
It seems caused by windows update version **1709**.
After I recovered my windows version to **1703**, the problem was solved.

Comment: I couldn't test your solution because we finally decided to use visual studio code instead, but thanks anyway^^

Comment: Has Windows now fixed this issue? or do we need to wait for another patch upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the 1709 (aka Fall Creator's Update) caused this. I was too low on space to keep the rollback. In another thread someone suggested that visual studio 2017 does not have this problem. I can confirm that is true; but this solution came (for me) with a few different problems. First, I can no longer deploy direct to my android phone. Second, my team-mates still on VS 2015 can no longer open the project at all! If you can move forward to VS 2017, you'll also need to install TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017 before you can compile again.