# Visual Studio 2015 closing files on file save

Tags: visual-studio-2015

So I've tried to find someone else online having the same issue as me, but with little success. I currently have an issue with only Visual Studio 2015 (Using Professional) where by if I have a file open and save it, not only does it auto-close the file from my IDE but it also removes the file from the Solution Explorer.

I have to close and re-open the project for the file to reappear; rinse and repeat every time I save a file and want to re-access it.

I've uninstalled VS 2015 (even ended up uninstalling VS 2017 too), I've used [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller).. And still after reinstalling VS 2015 this issue is still apparent. Are there any settings which may be causing this, or anyone aware of potential fixes/workarounds?

Comment: Refer : -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208157/files-disappear-from-vs-2015-solution-after-saving

Comment: It's probably due to a 3rd party extension loaded in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is your file by any chance located on a cloud drive? This has given me very similar issues, though not exactly what you describe.

Comment: Nah, no cloud storage was used.

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that Windows expanded its file explorer event list. Visual Studio listens to these events. For some reason, when it receives a "file updated" event, Visual Studio thinks it's a "file deleted" event and acts accordingly.

Most answer focus on using a different version of Windows or Visual Studio, which (in my opinion) isn't a solution, it's avoiding the problem. [This hotfix, however, fixed the issue in VS2015 for me](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4089821/files-disappear-from-project-after-saving-in-visual-studio-2015).

Comment: This answer should be accepted as solution. Thanks @Flater

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue, but it did not remove the file only closing it after saving.

**Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019**
Version 16.5.5

**Microsoft .NET Framework**
Version 4.8.03752

**Microsoft Windows 10 Pro**
Version 1909
Build 18363.900

issue reported at Micrososft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/961001/vs-2019-is-closing-files-on-save.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue with VS2015 on Cordova project. The only solution I found is using another text editor outside the project.

Comment: is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this happens to me too. The only solution I've found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882418/2471497): downgrading windows. In my case windows 10 build #1607 works correctly.

Comment: Yeah, after reading the post Krunal made I decided to re-create my project in VS 2017 and migrate the code across.

Comment: So that means do we need to use VS 2017 Professional and not vs 2015 ?